# Moving ejabberd default DB to MySQL shows authentication failure

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to setup an **ejabberd server** on my *Amazon EC2 Ubuntu* instance.
With the default DB Provided by *ejabberd*, I can easily setup my connection. But I need to replace the *mnesia* DB with *MySQL*. I found some tutorials over the internet. From those tutorial I found out a solution. I will explain it as step by step.

I am using **ejabberd 2.1.11**. I made the following changes on **ejabberd.cfg** file

1. Commented the following line :

   `{auth_method, internal}`
2. Uncommented this:
    `{auth_method, odbc}`
3. Configured my MySQL DB

   `{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", "students", "root", ""}} // No Password set`
4. Change **mod_last** to **mod_last_odbc**
5. Change **mod_offline** to **mod_offline_odbc**
6. Change **mod_roster** to **mod_roster_odbc**
7. Change **mod_private** to **mod_private_odbc**
8. Change **mod_privacy** to **mod_privacy_odbc**
9. Change **mod_pubsub** to **mod_pubsub_odbc**
10. Change **mod_vcard** to **mod_vcard_odbc**

Then I installed **ejabberd-mysql driver** from the following link

http://stefan-strigler.de/2009/01/14/ejabberd-mysql-drivers-for-debian-and-ubuntu/

After making all these changes I restarted my *ejabberd server*.

Then I tried to login to my *ejabberd server*. It shows me the login prompt.

After entering the credentials it takes a lot time and then displays *authentication failed*.

Any help on the topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's dig into problem

- Your setup is working that means your config file is fine. But then
  Why does auth fails ?
- What schema you have in your *students* database ?

  - If you have a proper schema installed then does the user present in ur db's *users* table?
  - Have you also updated conf/odbc.ini with proper mysql details.
  - Even if both the conditions meet then I'll advice you to set mysql password and try again.

Let me know if that helps or not.

Update :-

- update your config with {loglevel, 5}
- then hit the login and tail all the log files.

odbc.ini

```
  1 [ejabberd]
  2 Driver      = MySQL
  3 DATABASE    = students
  4 PWD     = 
  5 SERVER      = localhost
  6 SOCKET      = /tmp/mysql.sock
  7 UID     = root
```

Comment: Thanks !
-> Students DB is same as their _ejabberd_ DB.

Comment: and everything else is also fine, means config of odbc.ini, users table etc.

Comment: Thanks !
-> Students DB is same as their _ejabberd_ DB.
-> When i checked there is no tuples inside _users_ table. I already given an admin user name and password at the time of installation. So, is that enough for ejabberd admin panel login ?
-> I tried on odbc.ini, But can you explain what all changes should do there?

Comment: there you go you must have a user in your users table. username should be same as your admin and then have password for it.

Comment: Okay, So The admin username and password we set at the time of installation has no value ???

Comment: it has value but you switched your database from mnesia to mysql. now mysql does not know that user

Comment: mark this as right answer if that solves your problem

Comment: definitely i will do. Let me check !

Comment: one more question,
do this  ejabberd-mysql driver is necessary ??
I updated my ejabberd to 14.05.

Comment: `2014-05-21 09:59:37.602 [error] <0.484.0>@ejabberd_odbc:log:574 p1_mysql_conn: init error 1045: "#28000Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"                         
2014-05-21 09:59:37.602 [error] <0.342.0>@ejabberd_odbc:log:574 p1_mysql_conn: post_start error login_failed` 

This error is repeating in error.log file

Comment: for ejabberd > 13.* it's not. Assign a password to mysql

Comment: You saved my life !!! Thanks a lot!! Its Working Now After Setting the MySQL password !!!

Answer (score 0):

One Major basic part that one can easily miss is that data which was previously stored in mnesia database will no longer will be available for your new configuration so again you have to create one admin user like this to access your admin account.

./ejabberdctl register admin  "password"

Comment: this is like this ./ejabberdctl register admin server "password"